# How to customize the schema in APIView

Tags: django

I have two class, CustomAPIView and ContestMessageAPI, where the ContestMessageAPI inherits from CustomAPIView. The specific structure is as follows (the irrelevant method is omitted):

```py
class CustomAPIView(APIView):
    """
        Custom APIView
    """
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)


class ContestMessageAPI(CustomAPIView):
    """
        Pass in the contest_id to get the corresponding match information
    """
```

Now I am modifying a parameter in the ContestMessageAPI class so that I can implement a function.

```py
class ContestMessageAPI(CustomAPIView):
    """
        Pass in the contest_id to get the corresponding match information
    """
    parameter = {'contest_id': 'Field description'}
    schema = AutoSchema(manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field(name=k, required=True, location="form",
                      schema=coreschema.String(description=v)) for k, v in parameter.items()
    ])
```

Since the fragments assigned to the schema code are fixed, I want to port this code to its parent class CustomAPIView, and CustomAPIView becomes

```py
class CustomAPIView(APIView):
    """
        自定义的APIView
    """
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    parameter = {'contest_id':'字段描述'}
    schema = AutoSchema(manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field(name=k, required=True, location="form",
                      schema=coreschema.String(description=v)) for k, v in parameter.items()
    ])
```

Then I want to configure the parameter variable in the ContestMessageAPI to implement the schema that modifies its parent class, but the discovery fails. After querying the data, the reason may be: the rule for loading the member variable is to load the member variable of the parent class first, and then load the member variable of the class, which causes the configuration of the class to be invalid, because the member variables of the parent class are executed first. Separate configuration in each subclass of CustomAPIView can solve the problem, but this will write duplicate code in each subclass, which is very object-oriented. Is there any way to solve this problem?